# Recursively read an HDF5 file into R

Tags: r, hdf5

I have a fairly deeply nested HDF5 file which I would like to read into R *recursively* into a list data structure. I can already read single nodes using the rhdf5 package. Is there a library that can do this or must I parse the tree myself?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Actually I have figured it out: rhdf5 already parses things recursively into a list if you give it a node, and the root node is simply "/". So h5read("filename.h5", "/") will read the whole thing recursively into a list.